# DataFrame apply filtering by other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

Can I make an apply of a function to a dataframe column by filtering rows with another column value?

My actual code is:

```
df['description_text_clean'] = df.description_text_clean[df['language']!='en'].apply(translate_to_en)
```

Where I am trying to filter the column of language by the ones that aren't english and I want to translate the description_text_clean column. But in the end I obtain that the description_text_clean column have been modified in the english columns by NaN and I want them to continue as they were.

Example DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Example text', 'en'], 
                   ['No es ingles', 'es'], 
                   ['I am again english', 'en']], 
                   columns=['description_text_clean', 'language'])
```

Actual result:

```
    description_text_clean  language
0   NaN                       en
1   It is not English         es
2   NaN                       en
```

The desired result will be to obtain a dataframe with all the texts translated to english with the **translate_to_en** function that uses google translate api:

```
    description_text_clean  language
0   Example text              en
1   It is not English         es
2   I am again english        en
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Thanks for your comments @anky. With this code you are extracting as in the apply the unique row to translate, but whenever you want to insert them to the dataframe it adds NaN values for all of the non existent rows (english ones).

Comment: my bad, didnt realize fillna would do nothing since we dont have those indexes, added an answer this time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad i missed a small detail in my comments, try with `.loc[]`,`series.mask` or `series.combine_first` or `np.where`

```
df.loc[df['language'].ne('en'),'description_text_clean']  = (
                     df['description_text_clean'].map(fun))
```

Or:

```
(df.loc[df['language'].ne('en'),'description_text_clean'].map(translate_to_en)
  .combine_first(df.description_text_clean))
```

Or:

```
df['description_text_clean'].mask(df['language'].ne('en')
                                  ,df['description_text_clean'].map(translate_to_en))
```

Or even `np.where`:

```
np.where(df['language'].ne('en'),
        df['description_text_clean'].map(fun),df['description_text_clean'])
```

Tested with dummy function:

```
def fun(x):
    return  1
df['description_text_clean'] =(df.loc[df['language'].ne('en'),'description_text_clean']
                      .map(fun).combine_first(df.description_text_clean))
```

Or:

```
df['description_text_clean'] = df['description_text_clean'].mask(df['language'].ne('en')
                              ,df['description_text_clean'].map(fun))
print(df)
```

---

```
  description_text_clean language
0           Example text       en
1                      1       es
2     I am again english       en
```

Comment: Thanks @anky it works fine with your solutions! Any manner to do it with apply?

Comment: @IMB just replace `map` in my solution with `apply` but IMO map should perform better

Comment: I have tried all of them and I will use **np.where** as it is the fastest one. The ranking goes like this (using the toy dataframe):

1.- Numpy          < 1    ms
2.- Mask                1.6 ms
3.- loc+mask         2.5 ms
4.- combine_first   8    ms